# Too few results from DBpedia

Tags: linked-data, dbpedia

I'm running the following query to get Athletes data from DBpedia

```
  SELECT * WHERE {

  ?player a <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/Athlete> .
  ?player foaf:name ?firstname .
  ?player foaf:surname ?lastname .
  ?player <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/country> ?birthplace .
  ?player <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/birthDate> ?birthDate .
  ?player <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/Person/height> ?height .
  ?player <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/Person/weight> ?weight .
}
```

but it only returns about 300 records! What's the problem with my query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had to make the last four attributes optional

```
  SELECT * WHERE {

  ?player a <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/Athlete> .
  ?player foaf:name ?firstname .
  ?player foaf:surname ?lastname .
  optional {?player <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/country> ?birthplace .}
  optional {?player <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/birthDate> ?birthDate .}
  optional {?player <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/Person/height> ?height .}
  optional {?player <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/Person/weight> ?weight .}
}
```

this way I could get all the records even when there are missing values

Comment: Note that you're not getting *all* the records straight off -- there are more than 650K solutions to this query, and you (currently) get 10K from the query as written.  You can add a few clauses -- `ORDER BY`, `LIMIT`, `OFFSET` -- to step through the full solution set.  Also note, you'll often get multiple rows for a single ?player -- because WIkipedia, and hence DBpedia, is full of dirty data. This may or may not matter to your use, but it's important to know.

Comment: How can I prevent retrieving multiple rows for the same player?

Comment: This depends on which attributes matter to you, and whether you care that there are other values for them.  If you just add `ORDER BY ?player` to your query, you can see some of the dirtiness present.  If you don't care about which value you get, `SAMPLE` is a useful tool.  The query becomes too long for a comment, and I think this is a distinct question (which may have an answer already), so I won't go deeper here.